# C# read dll returned values

Tags: c#, arrays, object, return-value, dllimport

I want to know if i can get a help for the following problem. the C# code is :

```
object retour_dll;

retour_dll = InteropAssembly.LabVIEWExports_vers_Cs.Envoi_datas_vers_Cs();
```

The dll returns a struct (or a cluster) with 3 arrays (a boolean, a single and an integer).

When I run the program (it works) and when i put a breakpoint a watch what is inside "retour_dll" I can see the 3 arrays with all the correct values.

My problem is that I don't know how to read the array inside "retour_dll" for putting them in 3 arrays.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J842P.png)

Comment: Can you show us, how it looks when you see  when you put breakpoint

Comment: You need to cast the return value of your dll to the correct type. If you have access to the return type `myType` (struct or class or whatever), use this with `var retour_dll_typed = (myType) retour_dll;`. If you _don't_ have access to it, you could do some trial and error by using `dynamic` until you figure it out. But as per your question it seems you have full control over the dll.

Comment: Also, in which language is the dll written?

Comment: The dll is written IN LABVIEW (i create it) the dll just returns arrays with values i want to read in c# code.

Comment: Retour_dll looks like an array of arrays, I don'know if you know LABVIEW programming, the return of the dll is a labview CLUSTER containing 3 arrays. I thank you again

Comment: I put a picture who shows then content of retour_dll after breakpoint